# How to change this substring logic so it will stop when the word is ended closest to the ending value in JS?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a string and need to cut it when it longer than 50 characters. The issue is that it cuts the last word.

```
 showName(name) {
      if (name.length < 50) {
        return name
      } else {
        return name.substring(0, 50) + '...'
      }
    },
```

How can I do it in a way that last word will be complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat naive approach that doesn't handle non-space breaks well, but it might be good enough.

```js
function showName(name) {
  if (name.length < 50) {
    return name
  } else {
    const short = name.substring(0, 50)
    const shortWords = short.split(/\b/)
    const lastShortWord = shortWords[shortWords.length - 1]
    const words = name.split(/\b/)
    const adjWord = words[shortWords.length - 1]
    if (lastShortWord !== adjWord) {
      return short.substring(0, short.lastIndexOf(' ')) + '...'
    }
    return short + '...'
  }
}

console.log(showName('A really long name that should span more than 50 characters but not cut in the middle of the last word in the allowed length'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a reverse loop of the string, until you encounter a space and the splice for there. A such:

```
function truncateFullWord(string, maxLen) {
  for (let i = maxLen; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (string[i] === ' ') return string.substring(0, i) + '...';
  }
}
```

so four your existing code you'd write it as

```
 showName(name) {
  if (name.length < 50) {
    return name
  } else {
    // use loop
    return truncateFullWord(name, 50);
    // use lastIndexOf
    const trimmed = string.substring(0, maxLen);
    return trimmed.substring(0, trimmed.lastIndexOf(' ')) + '...';
  }
}
```

Comment: Is ti possible to achieve the same result without loop e.g. with regex?

Comment: I'm not great with regex, but I've added another possible solution to my answer that doesn't use a loop, whereby `.lastIndexOf` is used to get the last space in the sub string